# Smooth Ternary (binary but 3) Time Series Data

Tags: time-series

Suppose we have a problem where an autopilot algorithm looks at a dash cam video with a pedestrian and outputs 1 of 3 predicted pedestrian intentions: `[-1, 0, 1]`. `-1` means the pedestrian is not going to cross in front of the vehicle, `0` means not sure or the pedestrian disappears, and `1` means the pedestrian is going to cross in front of the vehicle. Then we show the same video to a group of humans and ask for their estimation of the pedestrian intention. The task is to cluster AI intention with human intentions for now.

Now, the problem is that the algorithm prediction needs to be smoothed. In the figures below, black lines are human predictions and the red line is AI predictions.

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DhPgAHKwMoVrJvNakKkr7wL0cB9JdAIN/view?usp=sharing) is an example that the algorithm prediction doesn't need to be smoothed, as the overall shape matches with the predictions from humans. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B4L9Cl5I0mUmvN6e2uPX7feyJtfuSP-i/view?usp=sharing), however, definitely needs to be smoothed because the fluctuations from the AI output around 100 frames can be viewed as "not sure", which is `0`.

I don't think the traditional smoothing techniques, like moving average, can be applied here because the outcome of the smoothing operation needs to fall into one of `[-1, 0, 1]` as well. The data from both AI and human are essentially arrays with the same dimension, such as `[0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0] ...`. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple outputs (multi-label classification) instead of a single output. Then the output will encode the models estimated probability for that particular class. For example: (0.9, 0.1, 0.1).

Then you can use standard smoothing / aggregation / post-processing techniques, on each class. Such as rolling median/mean/exponential mean, morphological operators, Hidden Markov Model etc. Furthermore, you can tune decision thresholds on a per-class basis, which is often desirable when classes are imbalanced and/or the cost of misclassifications differ based on class. Hitting a pedestrian is probably worse than some uneccesary breaking...